# Alternative solution when Port 25 is blocked

Tags: email, smtp, port

i'm running a web server for hosting my wordpress website, i've also tried to setup a mail server (postfix+dovecot) but unfortunately my VPS host does NOT allow port 25 in order to avoid spam. They won't open it no matter what..Well it's for academic purposes so i'm not surprised. 
However they allow submission (Port 587) but i really really don't want to.

So, i'm searching for an alternative (free) solution to send emails from my own domain name.

I also have a second VPS which allows all ports, maybe i could setup there a mail server and use it as relay? Could that work? I'd like to mention that i have a wordpress plugin that let me choose SMTP host & port, authentication method, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it is the ISP not the host that has port 25 blocked. Ask your host to open an alternate port for SMTP. Then simply set your email to use SMTP via the alternate port.

Comment: Also, your firewall might be blocking port 25 inbound traffic. Get rid of that.

Comment: @ChakerMallek Its not ISP but the host. They stated that in FAQ too. They will not open port 25 no matter what :( I dont use firewall

Comment: I guess you can only choose to use the alternate Port 587.

Comment: @ChakerMallek So installing the smtp server in the second VPS will still not work? :(

Comment: How about making your own mail server? It seems to be a good idea :D . Doesn't??

Comment: Check this [link](https://vpsboard.com/topic/1506-running-your-own-mail-server/) on writing your own mail server.

Comment: @ChakerMallek Sorry i wasn't clear enough, i have already setup mail server in my main vps (postfix+dovecot) but since port 25 is blocked there is nothing i can do. submission sucks because not many recipient servers accept it.